# try catch not working in recursive function

Tags: html, recursion, html5-video, try-catch

**Objective**
What i am trying to do is catch the "Failed to load resource" error and put it in an alert window.

**Issue**
I am trying to catch a video that does not exist. Try catch is not catching the exception.

**Background**
I am trying to play through an array of videos, i continue to the next video when the previous one finishes. The issue is there wont always be a video for every element in the array. I have tried placing the try catch around just the play function. I have also tried placing the entire contents of the PlayArray() function in the try but no success, and i also tried placing the try around where the PlayArray function calls itself.
I am having no luck with the try catch, catching the exception.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- modernize older browsers -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

        <title>Starter File</title>

        <!-- enable responsive web design -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />

        <!-- stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link media="only screen and (max-width: 980px)" href="css/tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link media="only screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/videoPlayerQeued.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top-banner">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="images/fantasytv-logo.png"/>
                <div>your team, on your time</div>
            </div>

            <div class="provider-container-interface">
                <img src="images/yahoo-signed-in.png"/>
            </div>

        </div><!--end of top banner -->

        <div class="interface-container">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>MY LEAGUES</li>
                <li>SETTINGS</li>
                <li>SIGN OUT</li>
            </ul><!--end menu-->
            <div class="fix"></div>

            <div class="date-shift-banner">
                <div class="left-arrow">
                    <img src="images/left-arrow.png"/>
                </div>

                <div class="date">
                    June 23, 2013
                </div>

                <div class="right-arrow">
                    <img src="images/right-arrow.png"/>
                </div>
            </div><!--end date banner-->

            <div class="stats-profile-container">
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <div class="stats-title-container">
                        <div><div class="padding-stat-title-offense">OFFENSE</div></div>
                        <div><div class="padding-stat-title-pitching">PITCHING</div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fix"></div>

                    <table class="offense">

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>R</td>
                            <td>AVG</td>
                            <td>H</td>
                            <td>HR</td>
                            <td>SB</td>
                            <td>RBI</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>.000</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--end stats table-->

                    <table class="pitching">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>W</td>
                            <td>L</td>
                            <td>H</td>
                            <td>K</td>
                            <td>WHIP</td>
                            <td>ERA</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>.000</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--end stats table-->

                </div><!--end stats container-->

                <div class="player-profile-container">
                    <img class="player-picture" src=""/>

                    <div class="player-name-team-container">
                        <div class="player-name"></div>
                        <div class="player-team"></div>
                    </div><!-- end player name team container -->
                </div><!--end player profile container-->
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div><!--end stats and profile container-->

            <div class="video-roster-container">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <div class="video-container-padding">
                        <div class="fantasy-team">TEAM: <span>YANKEEFAN</span></div>
                        <div id="video-player">
                            <video  id="play-video" width="588" height="318" controls autobuffer>
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>    <!--end video container -->

                        </div><!--end video player-->
                    </div><!--end video container padding-->
                </div><!--end video container-->

                <div class="roster-container">
                <div class="play-all-container">
                <div class="play-all"><img src="images/play-all-arrow.png"/></div><div class="watch-all-players">Watch All Players</div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>

                    <ul class="player-video-buttons">
                        <li id="test"><span>C</span><span>Willin Rosario</span><span class="team">Colorado Rockies</span></li>
                        <li><span>1B</span><span>Chris Davis</span><span class="team">Baltimore Orioles</span></li>
                        <li><span>2B</span><span>Ian Kinsler</span><span class="team">Detroit Tigers</span></li>
                        <li><span>SS</span><span>Derek Jeter</span><span class="team">New York Yankees</span></li>
                        <li><span>3B</span><span>Evan Longoria</span><span class="team">Tampa Bay Rays</span></li>
                        <li><span>OF</span><span>Mike Trout</span><span class="team">Los Angeles Angels</span></li>
                        <li><span>OF</span><span>Josh Hamilton</span><span class="team">Los Angeles Angels</span></li>
                        <li><span>OF</span><span>Michael Cuddyer</span><span class="team">Colorado Rockies</span></li>
                        <li><span>U</span><span>David Ortiz</span><span class="team">Boston Red Sox</span></li>
                        <li><span>P</span><span>Clayton Kershaw</span><span class="team">Los Angeles Dodgers</span></li>
                        <li><span>P</span><span>Matt Harvey</span><span class="team">New York Mets</span></li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--end roster container-->
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div><!-- end video roster container-->
        </div><!--end interface container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play-all').on("click", function(){
        var videoFileArray;
        var pictureFileArray;
        var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player'); //current video
        var rosterArray = LoadRoster();
        rosterArray = FormatArray(rosterArray);
        videoFileArray = AddMovieExtensions(rosterArray);
        PlayArray(0, videoPlayer, videoFileArray);
    });
})


function PlayArray(index, ele, array, listener){
        var videoTag = '<video  id="play-video" width="588" height="318" controls>          <source src="{fileName}" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.     </video>';

        videoTag = videoTag.replace('{fileName}', array[index]);
        $('#video-player').empty();
        $('#video-player').html(videoTag);
        currentVideo = document.getElementById('play-video'); 
        try{
        currentVideo.play();
        }
        catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }
        if(index >= array.length){
            alert('End of videos');
        }
        index++
        listener = currentVideo.addEventListener('ended',function(){
                PlayArray(index,ele,array,listener);
        }, false);
}

function AddMovieExtensions(roster){
    var rosterArrayFormatted = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++ ){
        rosterArrayFormatted[i] = roster[i] + '.mov';
    }
    return rosterArrayFormatted;
}


function LoadRoster(){
//Loads current roster into memory from button labels
    var currentC = "Willin Rosario";
    var current1B = "michael Cuddyer";
    var current2B = "current 2b";
    var currentSS = "current SS";
    var current3B = "current TB";
    var currentOF1 = "OF1";
    var currentOF2 = "OF2";
    var currentOF3 = "OF3";
    var currentU = "This is A U";
    var currentP1 = "P1";
    var currentP2 = "josh hamilton";
    var rosterArray = [currentC, current2B, current1B, currentP2];
    // var rosterArray = [currentC, current1B, current2B, currentSS, current3B, currentOF1, currentOF2, currentOF3, currentU, currentP1, currentP2];
    return rosterArray;
}

function FormatArray(roster){
//remove spaces and lowercase all letters
var rosterArrayFormatted = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++ ){
        rosterArrayFormatted[i] = roster[i].replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
    }
return rosterArrayFormatted;
}

function videoTimeCounterUpdate(clipObject){
    var clipTime = clipObject.currentTime;
    clipTime = clipTime.toFixed(1);
    var runTimeUpdate = setTimeout(videoTimeCounterUpdate, 100); //Round to .x digit    
}
```

Comment: Have you thought of removing the null elements from the array before playing it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: yup i was doing that in the development proces, but in my final version the names will be populated even if there are videos available.....idk if i can check this beforehand but i thought my best solution would be to put the play function in a try catch and then return an alert saying there is no video for that player and then move on to the next video.

Comment: Why are you using a recursive function here. You have array beforehand. Just loop for each element in array and call non-recursive Play method.

Comment: I had written this using a for-loop for the length of the array and then had a Play video function called but because the for loop continues running the videos never pass ready state 0, until the last video resulting in only the last video playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the following to where you instantiate the video player it will trap that error for you and you can take action accordingly

```
document.getElementById("play-video").addEventListener('error', ooops, false);

function ooops() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("play-video").error.code)  
    // 4 will be returned if the video isn't found
    // MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
    // MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
    // MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
    // MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
    // MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: 5
    // just .error will give you the array of possible values as well as the .code
}
```