# Automatically playing audio HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to create a playlist on my site. I want my site to do if one audio track is finished then the second audio in playlist would play by itself.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:#A9A9A9">
<div class="container" style="width:60%;">
    <div class="row main">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title text-center">
               <h1 class="title">Listen</h1>
               <hr />
        <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" >
            <source src="http://jezecek.nostools.cz/music/cc.mp3">
             Your Fallback goes here
        </audio>
        <ul id="playlist">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="http://jezecek.nostools.cz/music/cc.mp3">
                 cc
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://jezecek.nostools.cz/music/gg.mp3">
                gg
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here Javascript that doesnt work (screenshot):

https://gyazo.com/278e432d299ac1cef0f57f939c28bd94

Thanks for any help or advice

Comment: please add the js code in your question, do not link to a screenshot.

Comment: In future copy the code to your question instead of sending a screenshot

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706924/java-script-all-audio-plays-at-once-when-attempting-to-play-audio-one-by-one-in

Comment: have you tried to figure out _what_ part of the js doesn't work?

Comment: Well I tried to add a code as usual, but for some reason the syntax just wasnt showing as it should.
Yes, the console is printing this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of undefined
    at init (playlist.js:8)
    at playlist.js:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do, is use an `iframe` and then with JavaScript, you have a `setTimeout()` function that will go after a certain time. This way, with Javascript, after a certain amount of time (however long into the video you want it to change videos), it would change the source of the other video.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger 'on the end of playback' on either audio or video, you use this tag `<audio|video onended="myScript">` where the script is in javascript.  So you use javascript to control the second audio.  I used jQuery html element to replace the html and trigger autoplay.